# How to add bitcoin to allowed currency list

Tags: magento-1.9, currency

```
System->Configuration->Currency setup->Allowed currencies
```

How am i supposed to add a new currency(say bitcoin) to this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved this issue. I have added this code to `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml`:

```
<currency type="BTC">
    <displayName>Bitcoin</displayName>
    <displayName count="one">Bitcoin</displayName>
    <displayName count="other">Bitcoins</displayName>
    <symbol>BTC</symbol> 
</currency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also sell the BCH in your digital wallet through a peer-to-peer trading platform, such as Local.Bitcoin.com. Create an account and list the amount of BCH you want to sell, as well as which payment type you'd like to accept. This can include in-person cash payments or online payments such as bank transfers.